# Table not created at the time of installing a custom module

Tags: 7

#### my_register.install

```
<?php

  function my_register_schema() {
  $schema['my_register'] = array(
   'description' => 'Registered users detail',
   'fields' => array(

  'rid' => array(
    'type' => 'serial',
    'not null' => TRUE,
    'description' => 'unique ID',
  ),

  'my_register_uname' => array(
    'type' => 'varchar',
    'length' => 255,
    'not null' => TRUE,
    'description' => 'Some description here.',
  ),

  'my_register_fathername' => array(
    'type' => 'varchar',
    'length' => 255,
    'not null' => TRUE,
    'description' => 'Some description here.',
  ),

  'my_register_phone' => array(
    'type' => 'varchar',
    'length' => 10,
    'not null' => TRUE,
    'description' => 'Some description here.',
  ),

  'my_register_email' => array(
    'type' => 'varchar',
    'length' => 50,
    'not null' => TRUE,
    'description' => 'Some description here.',
  ),

  'gender' => array(
    'type' => 'varchar',
    'length' => 10,
    'not null' => TRUE,
    'description' => 'Some description here.',
  ),

  'my_register_address' => array(
    'type' => 'varchar',
    'length' => 255,
    'not null' => TRUE,
    'description' => 'Some description here.',
  ),

  'Education' => array(
    'type' => 'varchar',
    'length' => 50,
    'not null' => TRUE,
    'description' => 'Some description here.',
  ),

  'my_register_language' => array(
    'type' => 'varchar',
    'length' => 50,
    'not null' => TRUE,
    'description' => 'Some description here.',
  ),
),
'primary key' => array('rid'),
);

return $schema;
}
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Are there any error messages? Did you have the module installed before you added the hook_schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found that if you update hook_schema() while your module is enabled there seems to be an issue getting Drupal to generate your tables even after disabling and enabling your module. To get around this:

1. disable the module
2. uninstall the module (via the modules page)
3. enable the module

Your updated schema should now be reflected in the database. Hope this helps someone because I was scratching my head for a while at this.